# Find two latest and oldest documents which containing specific field values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Technologies:** Mongoose, NodeJS, MongoDB

**Question**

The following document will save on the MongoDB cluster every 10 seconds.

```
{
  "_id": "6003fafc04cb3727e40812b2",
  "currentRound": 39300,
  "current": 4.131929,
  "voltage": 245.855,
  "power": 956.5797,
  "frequency": 50,
  "totalPower": 1167.862,
  "importPower": 1167.862,
  "exportPower": 0,
  "powerFactor": 0.998356,
  "rssi": -59,
  "deviceId": "EC:FA:BC:63:02:C1",
  "slaveId": 201,
  "timestamp": 1610873596543,
  "__v": 0
}
```

There is two types of slave ids (101, 201) documents saving on the same collection and each slave id is having a specific device id. I want to retrieve the most latest and oldest 101 and 201 containing document by using yesterday's timestamps, starting 0:00 AM to 11:59 PM.

**Attempt**

I have tried the following solution. but `distinct('slaveId')` returns only the distinct specific field attribute only.

```
        const latestPGStats = await PGStat
            .find({
                deviceId: { $in: deviceIds },
                timestamp: { $lte: endTimestamp, $gte: startTimestamp }
            })
            .sort({ timestamp: -1 })
            .distinct('slaveId')
            .limit(2);
```

I have seen some peoples suggest using mongo aggregation. but I don't have knowledge about that domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `aggregate()`,

- `$match` your conditions
- `$facet` to separate results, first is latest and second is oldest
- `$sort` by `timestamp` in descending order
- `$group` by `slaveId` and get $first document in latest and $last document in oldest
- $limit` to get single document

```
const latestPGStats = await PGStat.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      deviceId: { $in: deviceIds },
      timestamp: { $lte: endTimestamp, $gte: startTimestamp }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
  {
    $facet: {
      latest: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$slaveId",
            root: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
          }
        },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ],
      oldest: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$slaveId",
            root: { $last: "$$ROOT" }
          }
        },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: perfect!. that solved my issue. but i have to add limit as 2 because always i need to get two distinct slave id containing documents. thank you very much @turivishal